# How to avoid cursor and loop in PL/SQL to get data in a variable with new line?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

For example: I have a table `TBS` having only one field `COL` contains `'A'` .. `'Z'` values.

As there is function `wm_concat(COL)` which gives output `'A, B, C,..,Z'` that can be store in a variable. Similarly, is there any function which can give the output like

```
A
B
C
D
```

and can be store in a variable.

**Note**:-
I tried to optimize the below code into a single query.

```
--PL/SQL Code
temp  VARCHAR2(4000):='';
cursor C for select COL from TBS;
BEGIN
for i in C LOOP
    temp := temp || i || CHR(13) || CHR(10);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Can you show some expected output for example data? I am not quite sure what it is you're trying to achieve here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `listagg()` where you can define the delimiter.

```
SELECT listagg(col, chr(13) || chr(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col) col
       FROM tbs;
```

Comment: Thanks @sticky bit . I got the solution. but can please explain the use of this 'WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COL)' as my table has only one field.

Comment: That let's you define an order on the concatenated values. And is required per syntax. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030 As you only have one column you can of course only use one column there. Or try if a constant is accepted (maybe not, I'm not sure), which effectively meant no order.

Comment: @stickybit is partition by is for the subgroup by within the specific group ?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja: `PARTITION BY` is only valid in the `OVER` clause, which used for the windowed/analytic version of the function and defines the groups there. But that isn't needed for your example where the aggregating version is sufficient.

Comment: No, actually it wasnt a part of the OP's query as such just was asking in general the `list_agg over(partition by name)` I thought if we need to have a subgroup within a group then make use of partition by just like in Teradata